# cause permission denied while execute golang syscall.MProtect

Tags: go

When I use package syscall like this:

```
 err := syscall.Mprotect(page, syscall.PROT_READ|syscall.PROT_WRITE|syscall.PROT_EXEC)
```

error occurs as below

```
permission denied
```

It seems EACCES error in C. What should I do?

Comment: my MacOS upgraded to Catalina and then caused this problem

Comment: Seems like page has read-only flag.

Comment: Are you using the monkey package? I'm having the same issue. Perhaps you can edit the question to include the package name for people to find this question easier.

Comment: Check here for an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61924409/976724