# Using mprotect to make text segment writable on macOS

Tags: xcode, macos, text, code-signing-entitlements, mprotect

This is essentially what I'm trying to do,

```
#include <sys/mman.h>

int zero() {
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    return mprotect((void *) &zero, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);
}
```

so I'm trying to make code writable, essentially. This doesn't work on the current macOS (Catalina 10.15.2), it just returns `-1` and sets `errno` to `EACCES`, which as far as I know is because of lack of entitlement/code signing. I've found the entitlement I need to set, but I have no idea how to go about that, nor how to actually sign it..

If I run `codesign -d --entitlements :- <path_to_app>`, it fails with `code object is not signed at all`, even though I've tried configuring signing in Xcode for a while (I have a certificate and so on). So how should I go about this? Actually signing it isn't obvious with Xcode, so I'm fairly clueless.

Comment: It is the problem of `PROT_WRITE` in MacOS Catalina. We could not fix it by passing all the flags in entitlements.

Comment: We have test to codesign with all the entitlements, such as `com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit`, `com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory` and `com.apple.security.cs.disable-executable-page-protection` but it didn't work. This could be the issue of MacOS Catalina and hop developers from Apple could fix it.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a definitive answer, but it's a workaround.

Your problem is caused by changes of the linker (ld64) in macOS Catalina. The default value of the `max_prot` attribute of the `__TEXT` segment in the Mach-O header has been changed.

Previously `max_prot` default value was `0x7` (`PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC`).
The default value has now been changed to `0x5` (`PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC`).

This means that `mprotect` cannot make any region that resides within `__TEXT` writable.

In theory, this should be resolved by providing the linker flag `-segprot __TEXT rwx rx`, but this is not the case. Since Catalina, the `max_prot` field is ignored. Instead, `max_prot` is set to the value of `init_prot` (see [here](https://github.com/apple-opensource/ld64/blob/fd3feabb0a1eb18ab5d7910f3c3a5eed99cef6ab/src/ld/Options.cpp#L374-L379)).

To top it all off, `init_prot` cannot be set to `rwx` either due to macOS refusing to execute a file which has a writable `__TEXT(init_prot)` attribute.

A brute workaround is to manually modify and set `__TEXT(max_prot)` to `0x7` after linking.

```sh
printf '\x07' | dd of=<executable> bs=1 seek=160 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

Since that code snippet relies on the `__TEXT(max_prot)` offset being hardcoded to `0xA0`, as an alternative, I've created a [drop-in replacement/wrapper](https://gist.github.com/darfink/a756b88e999631d75cbbeefd3eee7e2d) for `ld` which respects the `max_prot` parameter of `segprot`.

Comment: You can bypass the Catalina `dyld: malformed mach-o image: __TEXT segment maps start of file but is writable` check with the workaround I've shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60505259/5329717

Comment: That's an interesting tidbit! In the case of `mprotect`, I'd say it's better to alter the `max_prot` attribute instead, but it's great to know that there are alternatives.

Comment: Thanks and it works for subhook programs with this command https://github.com/Zeex/subhook/issues/45