# ld64 segprot on MacOS Catalina not working?

Tags: 64-bit, ld, macos-catalina, darwin

I want to create a binary on MacOS Catalina (64 bit) with a data segment that can be made executable (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62052528/self-modifying-code-on-macos-catalina-x64) for details) but is not executable from the start.

I make my binary with

```sh
gcc -nostdlib -segprot __DATA rwx rw- ....
```

I also created an object file with gcc and then called ld directly. The ld version is

```sh
$ ld -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-530
BUILD 18:57:17 Dec 13 2019
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
LTO support using: LLVM version 11.0.0, (clang-1100.0.33.17) (static support for 23, runtime is 23)
TAPI support using: Apple TAPI version 11.0.0 (tapi-1100.0.11)
```

That *should* make the data segment initially RW, but allow me to use mprotect to extend permission in that segment to RWX.

However, I notice that the __DATA segment is RW for initial and max permission:

```
$ otool -l jonesforth
.
.
.
Load command 2
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 312
  segname __DATA
   vmaddr 0x0000000100001000
   vmsize 0x0000000000024000
  fileoff 4096
 filesize 4096
  maxprot 0x00000003
 initprot 0x00000003
   nsects 3
    flags 0x0
Section
.
.
.
```

Is there something I'm missing? The darwin documentation [here](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ld64.1.html) says:

```
-segprot name max init (32-bit only)

              Specifies the maximum and initial virtual memory  protection  of
              the  named segment, name, to be max and init ,respectively.  The
              values for max and init are any combination  of  the  characters
              `r'  (for  read), `w' (for write), `x' (for execute) and '-' (no
              access).  The default is `rwx' for the  maximum  protection  for
              all segments for PowerPC architecures and `rw` for the all Intel
              architecures.  The default for the initial  protection  for  all
              segments  is  `rw'  unless  the segment contains a section which
              contains some machine instructions, in which  case  the  default
              for  the initial protection is `rwx' (and for Intel architecures
              it also sets the maximum protection to `rwx' in this case).  The
              default for the initial protection for the ``__TEXT'' segment is
              `rx' (not writable).
```

Of course, that the darwin (32 bit only) documentation but it's the only thing I found.
I suspect that either gcc does not 'properly' support the darwin protection syntax, or it's broken, or things in darwin changed from x86 to x64.

Any pointers would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: Note I tried to use gcc to compile and invoked the apple clang linker (ld) explicitely, with the same results. Is it possible the x64 linker has changed the segprot behaviour ?

Comment: Looking at [this](https://github.com/Apple-FOSS-Mirror/ld64/blob/30ccf3324b25680d3b08172b9f59c10d4bde2f67/ld64-134.9/src/ld/HeaderAndLoadCommands.hpp)  and [this](https://github.com/Apple-FOSS-Mirror/ld64/blob/30ccf3324b25680d3b08172b9f59c10d4bde2f67/ld64-134.9/src/abstraction/MachOFileAbstraction.hpp#L417) it does look like the protections are set correctly ... but they are not ...

Comment: This is due to a change introduced in macOS Catalina. You're viewing an obsolete version of ld64. You can see that `max_prot` is set `init_prot` here: https://github.com/apple-opensource/ld64/blob/fd3feabb0a1eb18ab5d7910f3c3a5eed99cef6ab/src/ld/Options.cpp#L374-L379

Comment: Oh dear, you're right – I misread this code. Do you have any insight if this change is on purpose ? There might be a chance that this was unintended, given that the manpage still clearly states that ld can accept maxprot and initprot.

Comment: I believe it's part of Apple's ongoing effort to tighten the security of macOS, but I have no source. Apple also uses an internal bug system only so I cannot determine whether they've expressed any sentiment on the issue.

Comment: In case you're interested, I've written a Python script that is a drop-in replacement for `ld`. It wraps `ld` and applies `max_prot` from any `segprot` argument after linking: https://gist.github.com/darfink/a756b88e999631d75cbbeefd3eee7e2d

Comment: Very cool, I can confirm that this works nicely for me. As far as Apple tightening security, I don't really buy it because this just more or less forces me to make the entire data segment rwx (which ld64 can do, at least for now), instead of just the forth definitions.

OTOH, it's not really adding security to unprotect just a bit of the data segment because the forth compiler could just issue the necessary mprotect calls itself to unprotect the entire __DATA segment to maxprot.

Unless you object, I'll wrap this up in the answer and quote your python script.

Comment: Yes I agree, in your case it's a degradation of security. But in when it comes to the `__TEXT` segment, you cannot set it to `rwx` (Catalina refuses to execute files with a writable `__TEXT` segment). Therefore this change prevents detours/code hooking from being used (e.g. modifying active code in `__TEXT`), which arguably hardens security. Sounds good to me! Hopefully Apple will present us a better solution.

Comment: Elliot, is this what the com.apple.security.cs.disable-executable-page-protection entitlement is for ?

Comment: I believe it's mostly relevant for applications submitted to the App Store? Judging by the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60654834/976724) it doesn't seem to affect the protection flags.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, something did happen on March 18:

Apple [committed a change](https://github.com/apple-opensource/ld64/blame/fd3feabb0a1eb18ab5d7910f3c3a5eed99cef6ab/src/ld/Options.cpp#L374-L379) that [makes ld always set](https://github.com/apple-opensource/ld64/blob/fd3feabb0a1eb18ab5d7910f3c3a5eed99cef6ab/src/ld/Options.cpp#L374-L379) maxprot = initprot for non-i386 architectures, so including x64, ie Catalina. It's unclear whether this was intentional, it's at odds with the ld manpage.

One workaround is of course to set the desired protection level for the entire segment in initprot. One can probably move the desired data/code into a separate segment if one wants to have finer grained control.

Another workaround, thanks to the comment from [Darfink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/976724/elliott-darfink): One can also change the linker  or modify the desired maxprot after ld runs. Darfink pointed out his [ld64 wrapper, a python script](https://gist.github.com/darfink/a756b88e999631d75cbbeefd3eee7e2d), to automate this.